# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 using 3.0 Callouts and Workflows

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, callouts

We are migrating to CRM 4.0 from 3.0. In this process, we have had our data migrated from our existing CRM 3.0 instance to a new CRM 4.0 instance.

This has been going all well and good until I got to the point of installing our existing callouts and workflow DLLs.

I know that I need to rewrite them, but our migration schedule does not have time alloted for this.

Can anyone point me towards how to install my CRM 3.0 Callouts and Workflow DLLs so that I see them in CRM 4.0? My Google-Fu for this subject has failed me.

Edit: At this point, I am about resigned to the fact I need to spend the weekend rewriting them as plugins.  If anyone can point me to a good resource that walks through taking a 3.0 callout and converting it into a plug, I'd enjoy that too. Everything I've found on 4.0 plugins assumes you are creating a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there's a method to natively register 3.0 plugins after upgrading. 3.0 plugins will work in 4.0, but only because CRM wraps them in the upgrade process and basically creates a new DLL with all your 3.0 callouts in it. If you didn't upgrade in place, I think you'll just have to recreate them.

Comment: I think you are right. I've got my pot of coffee made, there's beer in the fridge, and my schedule has been cleared for the weekend.

Answer (score 2):

I did not have any issues when I upgarded from CRM 3.0 to CRM 4.0.

CRM 3.0 callouts were writen in .NET 1.1. I opened, converted and compiled them with Visual Studio 2005 (.NET 3.0 installed on the machine too). I used the Plugin Registration tool to register complied callouts with the CRM 4.0.  I don't remember if I did any miner modifications but I know that everything went smoothly.

I hope this helps

Comment: I went ahead and rewrote them as 4.0 Plugins and Workflows, when I got down to it, it wasn't as difficult as it seemed. The book "Programming Dynamics CRM 4.0" by Steger, Snyder, Bosak, O'Brien, and Richardson was a big help.  Luckily we didn't have a huge number of them.

Answer (score 0):

CRM 3.0 callouts should generally work in 4.0, but *only* for the default organization of a multi-tenant configuration: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151075.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I saw that link. We only have one organization so we should be in good shape.  However, I didn't see anything telling me how to go about installing them. I about at the point of resigning myself to a weekend of rewriting them as plugins.